# Jquery .each on every node in XML with a name containing a specific string

Tags: jquery

```
<Manufacturers>
  <Manufacturer name="abc">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer><Manufacturer name="abcd">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer>
  <Manufacturer name="abcde">
    <flags=""/>
  </Manufacturer>
<Manufacturers>
```

I want to print out the names of just the manufacturers which contain the string 'bc' in the name

This is my attempt so far

```
$(xml).find("Manufacturers Manufacturer:has(name:contains('bc')) Name").each(function(){
            console.log($(this));
        });
```

but I get no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$(xml).find('Manufacturers Manufacturer[name*="bc"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Manufacturers Manufacturer[name*="bc"])

Comment: Found the error, you have an extra ) Code works now :) Thanks

Comment: Ooops! that was copy mistake. Corrected.